# Migrating MySQL to SQLite for Django Site

Tags: python, sql, django, heroku

(Migrate may not be the correct term I'm unsure) I'm trying to figure out how to change my Django site to register SQLite. Originally SQLite is the default for Django however I changed to MySQL because the original site I was going to host on (GoDaddy) was compatible with it. The only solution I thought of so far is changing the **DATABASES** info in my **Settings.py**. After changing my Settings to the defaults of

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
```

I ran into this error,

```
(env) PS C:\Users\kayak\New Work\google athentication\mysite> python manage.py makemigrations 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kayak\New Work\google athentication\mysite\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\kayak\New Work\google athentication\mysite\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\kayak\New Work\google athentication\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\kayak\New Work\google athentication\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 386, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\kayak\New Work\google athentication\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\kayak\New Work\google athentication\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\kayak\New Work\google athentication\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\kayak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\kayak\New Work\google athentication\mysite\mysite\settings.py", line 12, in <module>
    import heroku
  File "C:\Users\kayak\New Work\google athentication\env\lib\site-packages\heroku\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .core import from_key, get_key, from_pass
  File "C:\Users\kayak\New Work\google athentication\env\lib\site-packages\heroku\core.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .api import Heroku
  File "C:\Users\kayak\New Work\google athentication\env\lib\site-packages\heroku\api.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .helpers import is_collection
  
File "C:\Users\kayak\New Work\google athentication\env\lib\site-packages\heroku\helpers.py", line 57

    except TypeError, e:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized
```

Thanks for any incite and or help in advance!

Comment: Why are you migrating to SQLite? You have tagged this question with [tag:heroku]. Assuming that's where you plan to run your application, SQLite is a poor database choice as it is file-based. Heroku's ephemeral filesystem will cause changes to be lost frequently and unpredictably. MySQL would be a much better fit.

Comment: (The error here is because you are trying to run old code written for Python 2 with a Python 3 interpreter.)

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my code, I'm using SQLite because it have free support on Heroku, I would have used Postgre but It's gonna cost money to use it soon.

Comment: It's going to cost money to run dynos soon, too. SQLite won't work as you want on Heroku. If you already have MySQL working, why not just keep using it? Both JawsDB and ClearDB have Heroku addons with free tiers. These products all have subtle (and not so subtle) differences from each other. They're not drop-in replacements, and I don't recommend swapping them out frequently.